# Android Device (GPS) Direction

Tags: android

Using `Location.getBearing();` I seem to get randomly changing bearings.

Aka, I can turn the device around slowly and it wont notice, it just chooses its own random bearings.

I know the device is working, as the "You are here" icon in the Maps app on the tablet slowly rotates as I rotate the device.

Is there a different proper way of getting bearing? I am using the GPS. Maybe there is a better way to determine which direction you are facing.

Comment: did you get anything on your own ? I am facing the same behavior and looking for some kind of guidance .

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi Please see my answer :) dug it up just for you. 
Based on heroms answer, but with the orientation issue it posed.. fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get bearing from Accelerometer sensor and Magnetic Field (G-) sensor.

Here's a tutorial: http://android-coding.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/create-our-android-compass.html

Comment: Actually, this doesn't take into account, screen orientation. :/ Ill try and do my own work around.

Answer (score 3):

The `Location.getBearing()` returns the bearing that the GPS satellites computed for you. It is not a real time representation of the heading of your device. The Google Maps app uses the device's built in G-sensors to get the direction you are facing.

Comment: To clarify a little further, the GPS bearing is calculated by getting the vector between two points along the path of travel, rather than using an accelarometer to detect movement of the device.

Comment: @Jon So say, I move a meter backwards, it will assume Ive moved in the given direction but facing the other way (forward)? I did wonder why I need to contact the satelite to get my direction, since there's no way of it knowing my facing any more than the device does.

Comment: @Doomsknight yes that is correct, it will show you the direction of travel.  It calculates the directional vector between the point your at now and the point you just came from.  So as you said if you walk backwards it will show you as walking in the direction of movement, not the direction you are facing (counter to the direction of travel).

Answer (score 0):

Following from herom's answer using the link: http://android-coding.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/create-our-android-compass.html

I extended my class to implement the sensor: `extends Activity implements SensorEventListener`

And implemented as suggested, but modified it to take into account, the orientation of the screen.

Here is the code I went with:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch(event.sensor.getType()){
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
            valuesAccelerometer[i] = event.values[i];
        }
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
            valuesMagneticField[i] = event.values[i];
        }
        break;
    }

    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(
            matrixR,
            matrixI,
            valuesAccelerometer,
            valuesMagneticField);

    if(success){
        SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);

        double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
        //double pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
        //double roll = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[2]);

        WindowManager mWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        Float degToAdd = 0f;

        if(mDisplay.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            degToAdd = 0.0f;
        if(mDisplay.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            degToAdd = 90.0f;
        if(mDisplay.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            degToAdd = 180.0f;
        if(mDisplay.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            degToAdd = 270.0f;

        mapView.setFacingDirection((float) (azimuth + degToAdd)); //DEGREES NOT RADIANS
    }
}
```

Comment: can u have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692195/android-heading-direction-not-showing-correct-heading